# How does Google know to translate Unicode replacement characters (U+FFFD)?

Tags: encoding, translation, google-translate

I use OpenAI to write text in multiple languages, and despite my best efforts, I can't stop the periodic outputting of � (U+FFFD) characters in some languages. I even add the proper character encoding to the prompt, but it doesn't completely solve the issue.

That said, I was under the impression that it's impossible to determine the broken characters, and thus, it can't be fixed. But when I test the words with broken characters using Google Translate, it knows how to properly translate them.

For example:

```
mno��stva
pou��itím
dôle��ité
```

Google knows to translate them to:

```
multitudes
using
important
```

Is it just guessing, or how is it determining the broken characters?

Direct link to Google Translate page:

https://translate.google.com/?sl=sk&tl=en&text=mno%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDstva%0Apou%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDit%C3%ADm%0Ad%C3%B4le%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDit%C3%A9&op=translate

Comment: If you want to know how Google does something, why not ask them?

Comment: @Nico Haase Because I'd assume one of the largest companies in the world isn't going to respond with their method of interpreting broken character text. But a coder may know what they're doing so I can use it in my code.

Comment: Some types of misspelling can be translated just fine by Google translate. It has plenty of data for Spanish, French etc. For a less commonly encountered language (Armenian, Khmer, etc.), some testing suggests that it guesses the English translation based on another word that is spelled similarly, and the result can be very different from the intended.

Comment: For example, a while ago, someone mistyped "កូដ" (Khmer for "code") as "កុដ", which got translated by Google as "crown" because the mistyped spelling is similar to the Khmer word for "crown" ("មកុដ"), just missing a "ម" character.

Comment: If you have a complete dictionary, and an algorithm to judge how similar different spellings are, then you can make educated guesses about what the missing characters should be. Very often, if you input typos into Google search, it will respond with "Did you mean: ..." or even "Showing results for ..."?

Comment: It could be a simple regex against a complete dictionary (for valid Czech words *opáčit opálit opařit opažit* corrupted as *opa��it opa�it*) like [this](https://ssjc.ujc.cas.cz/search.php?hledej=Hledat&heslo=%5Eop%5Ba%C3%A1%5D.%7B1%2C2%7Diti&sti=EMPTY&where=hesla), or more sophisticated algorithm (e.g. search for words of *Levenshtein distance* less than 2)?

Comment: @Joe Are you aware of Google's [_Cloud Translation API_](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/detecting-language-v3)? You submit an HTTP request containing your data (i.e. text in some arbitrary language) and get back an HTTP response, where the JSON data returned includes the (probable) language of your data, and a degree of confidence in that language being the correct choice. I realize you are asking _how_ Google detects language, and that API doesn't shed any light on that. But if you just want to _use_ a third-party language detection API in your code it might help.

Comment: Google's Translation API is free for small volumes of data (_"First 500,000 characters* per month"_), but you would have to pay if you used it a lot. See [Cloud Translation Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing) for details. (Disclaimer: I have never used that API, and I have no connection to Google.)